# Random magic matrix giving unexpected results

Tags: matlab, octave, magic-square

I was trying to create random magic square **in Octave** and tried something like `rand(magic(3))`, and it gave unexpected endless results something like this:

```
 ans(:,:,1,1,2,1,1,1,1) =

 0.894903   0.296415   0.143990
 0.186976   0.305691   0.505485
 0.224823   0.834031   0.285508
 0.336706   0.318158   0.076293
```

On trying `rand(magic(4))` and for 5,6,7... it gave a message something like this

> error: out of memory or dimension too large for Octave's index type

What can be the possible reason for this vague result ?

Comment: what are you trying to do? magic(3) returns a 3x3 matrix. The function rand expects as arguments number of elements per dimension so you're creating a 8x3x4x1x5x9x6x7x2 matrix. For rand(magic(4)) the matrix would have prod(magic(4)(:))=20922789888000 elements which is too big to fit into memory

Comment: I saw the comments to Dan's answer, they are partially clarifying the problem. While `magic(n)` returns a square with the numbers `1:n*n` you are just talking about not-repeating numbers. That opens much more capabilities. Please update your question and make clear what a magic square is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you trying to do? `magic(3)` creates a *3*-by-*3* matrix in which all the rows and columns add up to the same number. `rand(x)` creates an *n*-dimensional matrix of uniformly distributed random numbers. If you call `y = rand([1,2,3])` for example, you will get a *3*-dimensional matrix of uniformly distributed numbers. The dimensions of `y` will match your input i.e. `size(y)` should return `[1,2,3]` and the number of elements will be `prod(y)`. Thus the number of elements of `rand(magic(3))` should be equal to `prod(prod(magic(3)))` which is `362880`. If you do this for `rand(magic(4))` then the number of elements would be over 20 trillion which is why you are running out of memory.

Comment: Then how can I create a random magic square? I mean octave returns the same n*n magic square everytime.

Comment: A matrix in which sum of all the elements of rows and columns is same.

Comment: And the diagonals? With the diagonals, I don't think you can create a random magic square (unless you randomly pick from the 8 equivalent matrices you'd get from rotation and reflection...). If you ignore diagonals then just shuffle the rows and columns around...

Comment: Yes the sum of elements of diagonals should be same and no number should repeat.

Comment: @HimagraChawla: Any reason you don't accept this as answer?